# Find a linear system of equations that has as solution set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given this solution set: [Solution Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRxWg.png)

I'm trying to find a set of linear system equations to satisfy the solution set. However, I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem. If I was given a set of equations I could find the solution set. That is, put the numbers in a matrix and put it in reduced echelon form. Then determine if it has infinitely many solutions, one, or none. But, in this case, it's going backwards... I have looked everywhere for sources, but I'm seriously confused.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}$ has solutions ${\bf x} = {\bf p} + c_1 {\bf u} + c_2 {\bf v}$ if $\bf p$ is one particular solution and $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are solutions of the homogeneous system 
$A {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$.  First find $A$ such that $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are solutions of the homogeneous system $A {\bf x} = \bf 0$.  This means that the rows of $A$ are solutions of ${\bf r} U = \bf 0$ where $U$ is the matrix whose columns are $\bf u$ and $\bf v$.  Find two such linearly independent solutions (think about why that is enough) to make your $A$.  Then take ${\bf b} = A \bf p$.